# Ant Design: How can I handle Button in Card extra onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to click X Button in Card extra to visible "Confirm Remove Todo modal".

### UI:

[image: UI]

## But...

the reality when I click X Button then it visible "Edit Todo modal" from Card event instead.

[image: After click X Button]

how can I fix it?

### Code:

```js
            {todos.map(todo => (
              <Card
                className={styles.CardTodo}
                headStyle={{ textAlign: 'left' }}
                bodyStyle={{ textAlign: 'left' }}
                key={todo._id}
                title={todo.title}
                onClick={() => handleSelectTodo(todo._id)}
                extra={
                  <Button
                    type="danger"
                    shape="circle"
                    style={{ color: 'white', zIndex: 10 }}
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveTodo(todo._id)}
                  >
                    X
                  </Button>
                }
              >
                {todo.description}
              </Card>
            ))}
```

.

---

.

## Thanks very much, guys

e.stopPropagation() is useful for me.

### And then I found another problem.

It is handleRemoveTodo() is the function that opens another modal.
But that modal didn't get "Todo object"

when I remove e.stopPropagation(), the modal will get Todo Object again
[image]

### Code:

### Todo component

```js
  const handleRemoveTodo = () => {
    setModalConfirmRemoveVisible(true)
  }

  const handleConfirmRemove = async todoId => {
    console.log('Hello', todoId)
    setIsRemoveLoading(true)

    try {
      await axios.delete(`/todos/${todoId}`, apiConfig)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      console.error(err.response.data)
    }
    await fetchTodos()

    setModalConfirmRemoveVisible(false)
    setIsRemoveLoading(false)
  }

  return (
      {modalConfirmRemoveVisible && (
        <ModalConfirmRemoveTodo
          visible={modalConfirmRemoveVisible}
          todo={todo}
          isRemoveLoading={isRemoveLoading}
          onConfirmRemoveTodo={handleConfirmRemove}
          onCancel={() => setModalConfirmRemoveVisible(false)}
          onConfirmRemove={handleConfirmRemove}
        />
      )}
  )
```

### Modal component

```js
const ModalConfirmRemoveTodo = props => {
  const { visible, isRemoveLoading, onCancel, todo, onConfirmRemove } = props
  console.log('ModalConfirmRemoveTodo', todo)
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        title={<Title level={3}>Remove Todo</Title>}
        okButtonProps={{ loading: isRemoveLoading, disabled: isRemoveLoading }}
        okText="Remove"
        okType="danger"
        onOk={() => onConfirmRemove(todo._id)}
        onCancel={onCancel}
      >
        Want delete {todo.title} ?
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have seen your update there. `But that modal didn't get "Todo object"` -> you mean `todo` prop, right? Would you mind providing a full version snippet of `Todo` component? The information is not enough for me to get your issue here.

Comment: Yeah, it is https://gitlab.com/fResult/todo-nevergiveup/-/blob/master/src/pages/Todos/Todos.js

Comment: Hey, I have downloaded and dived into your code. It seems like we have nothing to do with the `e.stopPropagation()` here. I guess you forget to call `setTodo` for storing the selected todo item into `todo` state when user clicks the X button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called **Event Bubbling**. When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

Please refer to this article for details: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#bubbling

Below is my solution to your problem. Instead of opening a modal, I just use a simple alert to simulate it.

**Your current problem**: https://codesandbox.io/s/event-bubbling-bojvq

You will see that the Chrome alert will pop up twice. The former is from the `onClick` of `extra`, the latter is from `onClick` of `Card`.

**Solution**: https://codesandbox.io/s/prevent-bubbling-zkxk6

Just add a simple `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the bubbling inside `extra` Button `onClick`. Please refer to this: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#stopping-bubbling for more information.

Back to your code, just simply update your Button's `onClick` like this:

```
onClick={e => { e.stopPropagation(); handleRemoveTodo(todo._id)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use stopPropagation() method on your event:

```
<Button
  type="danger"
  shape="circle"
  style={{ color: 'white', zIndex: 10 }}
  onClick={e => { e.stopPropagation(); handleRemoveTodo(todo._id)}}
>
  X
</Button>
```